# Failed decoding Data to a struct object

Tags: swift, xcode, encode

Hope you are doing good.
I have a problem that I am collecting record from an api and store it to a structure. Problem is that if a single value of the record is missing, the decoding process throws error. i.e whole record is gone. I'll be very grateful to hear you on this. Thanks.

Below is my code:

```
 HttpRequestHelper().GET(url: urlString, params: \["":""\], httpHeader: .application_json) { success, data in

        if success {
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(EmployeesModel.self, from: data!)
                
                completion(success, model, nil)
            } catch let error {
                completion(false, nil, error.localizedDescription)
            }
        } else {
            completion(false, nil, "Error: Employees Get Requests failed")
        }
    }
```

and the EmployeeModel is:

```
typealias EmployeesModel = [EmployeeModel]

struct EmployeeModel: Codable {

let age: String
let id: String
let name: String
let salary: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

    case id
    case name = "name"
    case salary = "salary"
    case age = "age"
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your response over here

Comment: just add `?` to all the var of your `EmployeeModel` that you think may sometimes be missing.

Comment: Share your API response here. It will be easy to figure out what is wrong with your model then.

Comment: Thanks for your time. My response is:
[{
 "age": "36",
 "id": "36",
 "name": "employee1",
 "salary": "3000"
}, {
 "age": "32",
 "id": "33",
 "name": "Inam",
 "salary": "4000"
}, {
 "age": "34",
 "id": "331",
 "name": "Ikram"
}]

Comment: What error do you get? At least replace `error.localizedDescription` with `error` to get the real descriptive error. And something like `completion(success, model, nil)` is outdated. Consider to use the [`Result`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/result) type.

Comment: @vadian Thanks for the feedback. Would you please share any best practice of Result ?

Comment: Declare `Result<EmployeesModel,Error>` and pass `.success(model)` or `.failure(error)`. On the caller side `switch` on the result.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Thank you. ? Optional solve the problem at all.

Comment: In last element ```salary``` is ```nil```.  But in your struct ```salary``` is not an optional value. So change ```let salary: String``` to ```let salary: String?```

Comment: OP, the suggestion above by @udi is much better than any of the posted answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try use optional. if you use same property naming don't have to use CodingKeys.

```
struct EmployeeModel: Codable {

   let age: String?
   let id: String?
   let name: String?
   let salary: String?

}
```